# Real UseCases for ngDoCheck (Angular9)

Tags: angular, use-case, angular9, angular-lifecycle-hooks, angular-component-life-cycle

I am a beginner in Angular & learning by myself and i have stucked in **ngDoCheck life cycle method**

> **According to Documentation:**
>   Detect and act upon changes that Angular can't or won't detect on its own.

**Parent Component:**

```
user={
   name:"xxx"
}

update(){
  this.user.name="yyy"
}
```

**Parent view:**

```
<button (click)="update">update</button>
<child-comp [inputprop]="user"></child-comp>
```

**Child Component**

```
ngDoCheck(){
console.log(this.inputprop);
}
```

As Far as I know,using this life cycle method to get the **latest changes in deeper level** that ngOnChanges can't detected the input property changes in deeper level.

In Simple words,ngOnChanges will detect the property changes only the reference of property gets changed.

> **In Above Example ngDocheck lifecycle method doesn't done anything to get the latest changes of property. But instead, change detection helps to get the latest changes in deeper level**

I wants to know the exact use case for using the ngDoCheck lifecycle method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your child component change detector may have the following strategies

1. default
2. onPush

In the default strategy, CD runs for any change in @Input() decorated properties

In the onPush strategy, CD runs when you pass a new object (reference) to the @Input decorated properties.

Regardless of the strategy, CD always run in the following scenarios,

1. An event such as click, submit gets fired
2. XHR call to work with an API
3. Asynchronous JavaScript functions such assetTimeOut() or setInterval() gets executed

Keep in mind that Angular CD can be visualized as a directed tree, which means all components can be seen as a node in a tree and Angular always runs CD from root node to the bottom of the tree.

[image: Anguular Componnet Tree]

Even there is an event fired in CC-121, Angular would run CD from the root component to the bottom. However, running of CD would stop at the node where strategy is set to onPush and you are not passing a new object in one of the @Input decorated properties.

So now you understand a bit about when and how CD runs, ngDoCheck() life cycle gets executed each time CD runs for the component.

I hope it helps.

Thanks

Comment: This is what i have understood CD triggers the ngDocheck(). But some implementation or process has done before triggering the ngDocheck. In short, we are getting the latest changes inside ngDocheck right. If possible, relate this method with real time. Thanks,I have understood a bit.

Comment: @debugmode- Still I am not clear in this life cycle

Comment: I have understood about Change Detection(CD).Thanks for that.So, CD triggers the life cycle methods one by one.For explaining my scenario,I have used the ngOnChange lifecycle method.
ngOnChange method will trigger whenever the input property value gets changed.Likewise, I am asking for this lifecycle method. If i am not wrong, inside this lifecycle method- we can get the **value of input property in deeper level** as mentioned in question.I wants to know, what exactly we can do with this lifecycle method. If I am repeating the same explanation, please forgive me.

Answer (score 1):

i see that you are confused between two lifecycle hooks.

In Angular , we can perform change detection using two different lifecycle hooks :

the **ngOnchanges lifecycle hook** and the **ngDoCheck lifecycle hook**.

But in some cases, the ngOnChanges is not enough to detect all changes because it uses the property reference to check the difference, so it can’t detect the changes if you update the object property.

Meanwhile, the ngDoCheck lifecycle hook allows us to perform our custom change detection so we can bypass the [ngOnChange lifecycle hook](https://xpertuto.com/angular-ngonchanges-lifecycle-hook/) limitations.

For example, if you pass a User Object from the parent component then you update the age or the username property of the User object, in this case the Angular will not fire the event to dispatch the ngOnChange callback. Because it has the same reference of the User object.

So you can resolve this problem by using [ngDoCheck lifecycle hook](https://xpertuto.com/how-to-use-ngdocheck-lifecycle-hook-in-angular/).

by using ngDoCheck , we can use more advanced tools like **key-value differs** and **iterable differs** services to perform custom change detections.

check this little example :

```
  //child-component.ts
import {Component, DoCheck, Input, KeyValueDiffers, OnInit} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit, DoCheck {

  @Input() user: any;

  changelogList: Array<string> = [];

  differ: any;

  constructor(private differs: KeyValueDiffers) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.differ = this.differs.find(this.user).create();
  }


  ngDoCheck() {
    const userChanges = this.differ.diff(this.user);
    if (userChanges) {
      userChanges.forEachChangedItem((changeRecord: any) => {
        this.changelogList.push('item changed : ' + changeRecord.key + ' ' + JSON.stringify(changeRecord.currentValue))
      });
      userChanges.forEachAddedItem((changeRecord: any) => {
        this.changelogList.push('item added : ' + changeRecord.key + ' ' + JSON.stringify(changeRecord.currentValue))
      });
    }
  }
}
```

the differ method inside the ngDoCheck returns un object that provides multiples advanced methods such as

**forEachItem**, **forEachPreviousItem**, **forEachChangedItem**, **forEachAddedItem**, **forEachRemovedItem**.

Comment: I tried above changes, but not working as expected, ngDoCheck not getting called when button triggers on parent component.